# TextField lowercase line

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, textfield

I need to get a distance between Baseline and Lowercase line inside **the scaled TextField**, using ActionScript 3. I marked it's with the blue arrows here: [image]

Does anybody knows how to get this value?

Comment: Based on the info provided in the diagram/by AS3 I don't think it's possible.  A fun puzzle, but unfortunately it appears impossible (perhaps this is somehow based on the font?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called the [x-height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height). Unfortunately, the Flash ActionScript API does not provide any way of getting the x-height for a typeface.

With some tricky techniques, you might be able to calculate the x-height yourself though. I am thinking you might be able to create a new textfield with just an "x" in it, and draw it to a bitmapdata. Then test the pixels to get the height.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s:String=yourTF.text; // preserve
yourTF.text='x';
var c:uint=yourTF.textColor; // get color
var bd:BitmapData=new BitmapData(yourTF.width,yourTF.height);
bd.draw(yourTF);
var r:Rectangle=bg.getColorBoundsRect(0x00ffffff,c);
trace(r.height);
yourTF.text=s;
```